# How to copy files and sub-folders

Tags: ruby, copy, fileutils

I'm trying to copy files including sub-folders, but I'm getting a `RunTimeError copy: unknown file type`.

I also created folders and files to test myself.

Folders and files for test:

```
 - D: 
   - backup_target 
       - target1 
           - file1.txt 
           - sub1 
               - sub_file1.txt 
               - sub_file2.txt 
           - sub2
               - sub1.txt 
               - sub.txt 
       - target2 
           - file1.txt 
           - file.txt
```

And I made a list as a text file in "backup_target_list2.txt":

```
D:\backup_target\target1
D:\backup_target\target2
```

My code is:

```
require 'fileutils'

LIST_FILE = "backup_target_list2.txt"

def copy_files(src, dst)  
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(dst))
  FileUtils.copy_entry(src, dst)
end

def dst_naming(src, src_head, dst_head)
  cur_date = Time.now.to_s[0..9]
  dst = src.gsub(src_head, dst_head + "/backup_#{cur_date}/")

  return dst
end

def get_backup_list(list_file)
  if !File.exist?(list_file) then
    return nil
  end

  path_arr = []

  File.open(list_file, "r") do |f|
    f.each_line { |line|
      path_arr.push(replace_delim(line).gsub("\n", ""))
    }
  end

  return path_arr
end

def replace_delim(str_obj, delim_org= "\\", delim_new = "/")
  if str_obj.class == Array
    str_arr = []

    str_obj.each do |str|
      str_arr.push(str.gsub! delim_org, delim_new)
    end

    return str_arr
  else
    return str_obj.gsub! delim_org, delim_new
  end
end

get_backup_list(LIST_FILE).each do |path|
  src = path
  dst = dst_naming(src, /D:\//, "C:/Users/MyName/Desktop/")
  print "src: #{src}\n=> dst: #{dst}\n"
  copy_files(src, dst)
end
```

It works fine with the test folders.

The problem is, I'm getting a RunTimeError when I run the code with my real folders:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1375:in `copy': unknown file type: D:/MyRealFolder (RuntimeError)
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:463:in `block in copy_entry'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1485:in `call'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:1485:in `wrap_traverse'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:460:in `copy_entry'
from copy_test.rb:8:in `copy_files'
from copy_test.rb:52:in `block in <main>'
from copy_test.rb:48:in `each'
from copy_test.rb:48:in `<main>'
```

The difference between "real" and "test" is that "real" folders have more sub-folders and more files.

I also tried `FileUtils.cp_r` and `FileUtils.cp` but I'm still getting an error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You're messing with the filenames and separators. As much as possible, rely on Ruby to convert filenames from using forward slashes to backslashes. Read [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html) for the IO class for more information. Also, File has `join` and associated methods that are aware of the `File::ALT_SEPARATOR` setting for your OS to help ease these things so take advantage of the built-in methods as much as possible.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for your comment! It helped. I solved `copy: unknown file type` problem.